# $\text{rk}(AB)=\text{rk}(BA)$ generally

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-rank

I would like to generalize the group of matrices of order $n\times n$, $A,B$ such that 
$\text{rk}(AB)=\text{rk}(BA)$.
I'm pretty sure that if $AB$ and $BA$ are nonzero, the condition will hold.
(clearly if $AB=0$ or $BA=0$ we can find counter-examples).
I was thinking for some time and couldn't find any proof at all.
I would like to get your help! Thanks!

Note: This wasn't asked here before! others have asked for counter-example 
for general $\text{rk}(AB)=\text{rk}(BA)$, but I added a condition.

Comment: Counterexample: $A(x, y, z) = (y, 0, z)$ and $B(x, y, z) = (0, y, z)$. Then $AB(x, y, z) = (y, 0, z)$ but $BA(x, y, z) = (0, 0, z)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try and find two $3\times3$ matrices $A$ and $B$ such that the rank of $AB$ is $1$ and the rank of $BA$ is $2$:
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\qquad
B=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Then
$$
AB=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}
\qquad
BA=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Your additional condition does not any anything substantial to the issue. Suppose you have an example that $AB=0\ne BA$. Then
$$
\pmatrix{A\\ &1}\pmatrix{B\\ &1}=\pmatrix{0\\ &1}
$$
is a nonzero matrix of rank 1 but
$$
\pmatrix{B\\ &1}\pmatrix{A\\ &1}=\pmatrix{BA\\ &1}
$$
is a nonzero matrix of rank $\ge2$.